# Unable to access a POST endpoint's reponse body as json

Tags: sveltekit

When trying to get a dummy response from a POST endpoint, the call to `res.json()` throws a serialization error in the client:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

This is the client side:

```js
const body = /* request body */
const res = await fetch(/* url */, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
})
console.log(await res.json())
```

And this is the endpoint:

```js
export const POST = async ({request}) => {
  /* do something with the request's body */
  return {
    body: {a: 1}
  }
}
```

I get the same error on the server side if I don't stringify the body in `fetch`, but I can't stringify it in the endpoint, as only plain objets (and errors) are allowed.

The outcome is the same with an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instruct the endpoint to send JSON, otherwise it will send the associated page as server-side rendered HTML. To do that add an `Accept` header:

```js
const res = await fetch(/* url */, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
})
```